# publish-subscribe pattern within an application versus between applications

Tags: google-app-engine, activemq-classic, publish-subscribe, pypubsub

Are publish-subscribe systems (e.g. ActiveMQ, Google App Engine pub/sub, and pypubsub) mainly for message communication between applications running over multiple machines with different memory spaces?  Or can they be used for handling efficiently message communication between components of a single application running within a single machine?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I tried to clarify.

Comment: have you seen here? https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs
At least for that one, it doesnt seem like its oriented to running it within a single machine. if you are worried about memory or overheads, im pretty sure it will have them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  pypubsub seems well-suited for use within a single application, but I just wanted to check if people have had experience with it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyPubSub was designed to provide message communication between components of a single application. This does not imply running within a single machine, although a single machine would be the typical scenario. If a "network distributed" application (one that consists of severa collaborating components spread across multiple machines) takes care of marshalling data between the machines, pypubsub could still be used to great effect.